# For Inaba’s theorem, how do we know the covering of points is independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, computational-geometry

In this paper on how many points can be covered using unit disks: http://2011.cccg.ca/PDFschedule/papers/paper5.pdf (page 5)

They give a proof of the fact that you can cover $10$ points using unit disks. I understand most of the steps except that they assume that the event of covering one point is independent of covering another. How do we know this is the case?

Edit: there was an inequality sign which I misread as an equality sign (somehow).

Comment: If I have understood correctly then the proof does not assume such independence. Would you mind sharing which line you found confusing?

Comment: @SumanChakraborty during the third step, when they turn the probability of a disjunction into a sum of probabilities. How do we know that the equality sign holds?

Comment: @SumanChakraborty oh, it’s an inequality sign, I seem to be blind. Then I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that they assumed such independence. The first equality is using the fact that $\mathbb{P}(A)=1-\mathbb{P}(A^c)$. The second equality is due to [De Morgan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) law. The "$\geq$" is due to [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20Boole%27s%20inequality,probabilities%20of%20the%20individual%20events.) (this does not require independence). Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: I just realised it was an inequality sign, man am I stupid. Thanks a lot!